# Dart: Convert map (Key / Value) into an Ordered List[]

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm receiving a document snapshot from firestore and I convert it into a `Map<String, dynamic>` and I know that maps are not ordered, however, I want to order the layout of my screen fields in a certain order.  Problem is, the order that I want to achieve is not alphabetical.  Here is a sample of my map:

```
Map<String, dynamic> customerInfo = {
  'projectName': 'John Doe',  
  'state': 'Arizona', 
  'city': 'Tempe',
  'estimate': 123000,
  'geoLocation': '12.345678,23.456789'
}
```

So, I am sending this map to a loop to iterate over keys/values and converting them into a list of widgets, however, for some screens I need to have 'State' be the first widget, and 'City' be the second widget, and vice versa for other screens.  Some maps will have more fields, those extra fields will not matter later on, I just want to maintain a certain order for certain fields if they exist.

I tried looping over the keys using a `switch / if` to match the keys and do a `List<Widget>().add(Text(key, value))` however, the generated list is still unordered obviously.  Here is a sample code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
class ProjectViews {
  List<Widget> projectDetailedView(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<Widget> fields = [];
    fields.add(
      Text(
        data['projectName'],
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: constants.primaryTextColor,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      ),
    );
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      if (key == 'state') {
        fields.add(dataField(key, value));
      } else if (key == 'city') {
        fields.add(dataField(key, value));
      } else if (key == 'estimate') {
        fields.add(dataField(key, value));
      }
      // switch (key) {
      //   case 'state':
      //     fields.add(dataField(key, value));
      //     break;
      //   case 'city':
      //     fields.add(dataField(key, value));
      //     break;
      //   case 'estimate':
      //     fields.add(dataField(key, value));
      //     break;
      // }
    });
    return fields;
  }

  Widget dataField(String key, dynamic value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            key,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          Text(
            value.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make sure the `List<Widget> fields` are added in a certain order.  The received map may contain 5 elements or 20 elements, only some of those need to be in order.

Can I use a `List<String>` arranged as my preferred order and convert the map based on this list?

Any other options to achieve this please?

Thanks

Comment: Actually when you create a map like that the order is maintained

Comment: The map is the result of a form being populated with data.  Example, the form has 10 fields, only the first one is required, all the rest is optional, so I keep adding to the map as data is entered in the form.  This is all fine, but when I retrieve the data from firestore the fields are not in the same order as the form to show them off, hence I need to order them so that I can display the data in proper sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my solution to the problem, basically you create a new ordered map with only the field names that you want to display in the order of display, then you populate this new map with the data/widgets.

```
class ProjectViews {
  List<Widget> projectDetailedView2(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<Widget> fields = [];
    final Map<String, dynamic> orderedFields = {
      'state': '',
      'city': '',
      'geoLocation': '',
    };  // this map has the items we want to display in the order we want
    fields.add(
      Text(
        data['projectName'],
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: constants.primaryTextColor,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      ),
    );
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      if (orderedFields.keys.contains(key)) {
        orderedFields[key] = dataField(key, value);
      }
    });
    orderedFields.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value.runtimeType == Widget) {
        fields.add(value);
      }
    });
    return fields;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a [LinkedHashMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html). It keeps the key insertion order.

Comment: Thanks, not possible, the map is already populated from firestore, what I am trying to achieve is convert this map dynamically into a `List<Widget>` to match the original order of the form on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseFirestore has a .orderBy() function that you can use to order your data when you query a collection.

```
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = 
await firestoreInstance.collection('collectionName')
         .orderBy('value', descending: false)
        .get();
```

Note: Your question seems like you're trying to get a list of Customer Info from firebase, so all you have to do is replace the 'collectionName' in my code with the name of the customer info collection. This is a querysnapshot because it queries the collection and gets you all the customer info in the collection.

You will also have to replace the 'Value' in my code here with the key of the value you want it to be ordered with. You can also choose whether it should be ascending or descending by setting the descending value to either true or false.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot use `OrderBy` on the keys as the alphabetical order is not what I am seeking, neither for the values.